# understanding bind9 query log

Tags: logging, bind, query

I'm running two bind servers a activated query logging but don't know what exactly i see here and not finding anything on the web which enlightens me;

```
31-Oct-2017 17:56:35.464 queries: client x.x.x.x#55638: query: test.example.com IN A +
31-Oct-2017 17:56:35.464 queries: client x.x.x.x#55638: query: test.example.com IN A +
31-Oct-2017 16:34:07.505 queries: client x.x.x.x#2968: query: test.example.com IN A -ED
31-Oct-2017 16:45:23.316 queries: client x.x.x.x#36192: query: test.example.com IN A -EDC
31-Oct-2017 18:02:12.711 queries: client x.x.x.x#37001: query: test.example.com IN A +E
```

At the end of the lines A-, A+, -E, +E, -ED, -EDC is what i try to understand;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is documented in the BIND Administrator Reference Manual and source tarball.

From the [ICS webpage](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00434);

> The query log entry first reports a client object identifier in
>   @0x format. Next, it reports the client's IP
>   address and port number, and the query name, class and type. Next, it
>   reports whether the Recursion Desired flag was set (+ if set, - if not
>   set), if the query was signed (S), EDNS was in used along with the
>   EDNS version number (E(#)), if TCP was used (T), if DO(DNSSEC Ok) was
>   set (D), if CD (Checking Disabled) was set (C), if a valid DNS Server
>   COOKIE was received (V), or if a DNS COOKIE option without a valid
>   Server COOKIE was present (K). After this the destination address the
>   query was sent to is reported. Note: This reflects BIND 9.11.0
>   behaviour.